# SQL query to find both 4 character and 6 character values from two tables

Tags: sql, database, db2

Below are the two tables I am working with, along with the columns in the tables:

```
**## Table 1 ##**

Grantee Column w/sample data

Grantee
----------
CLAT

CLATX1

DJSD

DJSDX3

ADKS

ADKSX5

DKHS
```

```
**## Table 2 ##**

Inact_ID Column w/sample data

Inact_ID
----------
CLAT

DJSD

ADKS

DKHS
```

With the following Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.GRANTEE           
FROM TABLE1 A             
WHERE                      
EXISTS(SELECT 1                     
        FROM TABLE2 B     
        WHERE A.GRANTEE= B.INACT_ID);
```

```
These are my results:

CLAT

DJSD

ADKS

DKHS
```

4 Character ID's Returned - Not everything I want(Also want 6 character ID's associated with the 4 character ID's)

In addition to getting those 4 character ID's, some of those 4 character ID's also have another ID with the following naming convention - A02WXn, where X is a constant, and n is a number from 0-9, which is a 6 character ID. I want to be able to include the 6 character ID, if it exists along with the 4 character ID. The 6 character ID's only exist in Table 1.

UPDATE: I think I might be closer to a solution, hope this can clarify more what I want as results.

`SELECT A.GRANTEE FROM TABLE1 A INNER JOIN (SELECT B.INACT_ID FROM INACTIVE_USERS B) ON A.GRANTEE LIKE '%' || B.INACT_ID || '%';`

```
(Note - This was done on Postgres, and worked, but I can't get it to run in DB2)
Results from Postgres Below:(Desired Results - Both 4 character ID and 6 Character ID if exists)

GRANTEE
--------
CLAT

CLATX1

DJSD

DJSDX3

ADKS

ADKSX5

DKHS
```

Comment: How about `...WHERE LEFT( A.GRANTEE, 4 ) = B.INACT_ID`?

Comment: Artjom B. - Thanks for the edit.

mustaccio - I appreciate the response! When I edit my WHERE CLAUSE to match what you have, I get incorrect results. I am getting ROWS returned that are not just 4 or 6 characters. I am wanting only the 4 character ID's and their associated 6 character ID if it exists.

Thanks

Comment: Then you need to provide more meaningful sample data, including exceptional cases. My suggestion would work perfectly with your existing sample.

Comment: Mustaccio - I updated with more information. I hope this helps.

Comment: I am able to get matching first 4 character positions in both tables, but I only want the result set to always include the 4 character ID and its associated 6 character ID if it exists.

I want no other values returned other than 4 character(ASDF) or 6 character(ASDFXn ID's) if they exist along with it's associated 4 character ID.

Right now I get values no matter how many characters they may be, as long as the first 4 characters match. I feel I am closer, but still can't figure this out.

I only need ASDF and ASDFXn ID's. Nothing other than 4 or 6 characters returned.

Does this help clarify?

Comment: Then you can simply add something like `...AND ( LENGTH(A.GRANTEE) = 4 OR LENGTH(A.GRANTEE) = 6 )`, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below SQL :

```html
SELECT DISTINCT A.GRANTEE           
FROM TABLE1 A             
WHERE                      
EXISTS(SELECT 1                     
        FROM TABLE2 B     
        WHERE substring(A.GRANTEE,1,4)= B.INACT_ID);
```

**I tried same thing in Sybase DB. It worked fine !**

```html
create table #temp1
(
GRANTEE varchar(125)
)
insert into #temp1 values('A02W')
insert into #temp1 values('A02WX2')
insert into #temp1 values('DBDS')
insert into #temp1 values('DBDSX4')
insert into #temp1 values('A03')
insert into #temp1 values('ASKDLAKDJD')

create table #temp2
(
INACT_ID varchar(4)
)
insert into #temp2 values('A02W')
insert into #temp2 values('AAAB')
insert into #temp2 values('AVCD')
insert into #temp2 values('SSLD')

select * from  #temp1
select * from  #temp2


SELECT DISTINCT A.GRANTEE           
FROM #temp1 A             
WHERE                      
EXISTS(SELECT 1                     
        FROM #temp2 B     
        WHERE substring(A.GRANTEE,1,4) = B.INACT_ID);
```

Comment: If I use the Substr(A.GRANTEE,1,4)=B.INACT_ID clause, I get rows returned that are not just 4 and 6 characters like a I am after.

I rephrased and added some updates to my original post, if that will help clarify.

Sorry for any confusion. I appreciate you input!

Comment: Thanks! If this is resolved please mark this as Answer.

Comment: The query you provided didn't work for what I was trying to retrieve.

Comment: I didnt see CLATX2 in your Source Data of table1. How come it came in expected result? Could you please explain ? Becuase i am trying similar data and i am getting below result :CLAT
CLATX1
DJSD
DJSDX3
ADKS
ADKSX5
DKHS

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. That was a typo. It should be CLATX1. I updated that. 

WHERE                      
EXISTS(SELECT 1                     
        FROM #temp2 B     
        WHERE substring(A.GRANTEE,1,4) = B.INACT_ID);

So the substring function is still qualifying rows that contain the first four characters, as well as any other characters that may be after that?

For example,
RESULTS - 

CLAT
CLATX1
CLAT4IDKSAKA
CLATSHDFSDHF
CLATAHAHAHAHAHAJAJAJA

Comment: ...I'd start with this `WHERE` clause, then probably add something to check for length, and possible a couple more to look for the digit/constant.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT A.GRANTEE           
FROM TABLE1 A             
WHERE                      
EXISTS(SELECT 1                     
        FROM TABLE2 B     
        WHERE substring(A.GRANTEE,1,len(B.INACT_ID))= B.INACT_ID);       Try Above Solution.